# How to return the result from a raw query (Sequelize) to GraphQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, graphql

I'm newbie with GraphQL and Sequelize but I have developed a test where I can make querys and get results from Graphiql using the functions of Sequalize, but I'm interested in making more complex querys with querys with several tables.

Now, this code works fine:

**schema.js**

```
import {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLFloat,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLSchema
} from "graphql";
import { DB } from "../db";
import {DateTime} from "../scalar/dateTime";
import {Player} from "./Player";
import {League} from "./League";
import {Group} from "./Group";
import {Season} from "./Season";

const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Query",
    description: "This is root query",
    fields: () => {
        return {
            players: {
                type: GraphQLList(Player),
                args: {
                    id: {
                        type: GraphQLID
                    }
                },
                resolve(root, args){
                    return DB.db.models.tbl003_player.findAll({where: args});
                }
            },
            leagues: {
                type: GraphQLList(League),
                args: {
                    id: {
                        type: GraphQLID
                    }
                },
                resolve(root, args){
                    return DB.db.models.tbl001_league.findAll({where: args});
                }
            },
            groups: {
                type: GraphQLList(Group),
                args: {
                    id: {
                        type: GraphQLID
                    }
                },
                resolve(root, args){
                    return DB.db.models.tbl024_group.findAll({where: args});
                }
            },
            seasons: {
                type:GraphQLList(Season),
                args: {
                    id: {
                        type: GraphQLID
                    } 
                },
                resolve(root, args){
                    return DB.db.models.tbl015_seasons.findAll({where: args})
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: Query
});

module.exports.Schema = Schema;
```

So, I would like to make an easy test to know how to return the data from a raw query to GraphQL. I have read that resolve method returns a promise, and I have tried to return a promise with the result of the query, but it doesn't work.

```
    players: {
        type: GraphQLList(Player),
        args: {
            id: {
                type: GraphQLID
            }
        },
        resolve(root, args){
            DB.db.query("select * from tbl003_player where id = 14",
            {raw: true, type: DB.db.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then((players)=>{
                let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                    resolve(players);
                });
                return myPromise;
            }).catch((reject)=>{
                console.log("Error: " + reject);
            });
        }
    },
```

Therefore, how can I return data from a query with Sequelize to GraphQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return the promise you get from sequelize. You are also doing a lot of work that is not required after your promise. Maybe read more about promises before moving on :)

```
resolve(root, args){
  return DB.db.query(
    "select * from tbl003_player where id = 14",
    { raw: true, type: DB.db.QueryTypes.SELECT }
  );
}
```

Comment: OMG!!! It works!!! Thank you so much for your apreciated help @Herku!!!!

Comment: My pleasure! Now it's on you to understand why it works :)